# Why a hash function in a manner similar to CBC-MAC is not collision-resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, cbc-mac

I'm reading the book *[The Joy of Cryptography](https://joyofcryptography.com/)* by Mike Rosulek.

When reading Chapter 11, on the hash function, I found a very interesting exercise. Does anyone have ideas on how to prove this?

Please see the image below for full details of the question.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. Solving yourself will give you a great experience. What do you ever think about this? You can write them and we will guide you to the point. Note that that is very easy: Small hint: in finding collisions the attacker is free to choose the inputs, that is different from 1. and 2. pre-image attacks.

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you for your help and hint. Currently, what I know is that different inputs can result in the same XOR. For example: 1010 XOR 1111=0101  and 0000 XOR 0101 = 0101. I think it may be relevant to this point, but I might lack the knowledge to describe it further. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Almost. What if you construct another message just removing the $x_1$?  What modification does the second shorter message need to have the same hash value as the original message?

Comment: @kelalaka so let's say a message x= x1 || x2, I construct the second shorter message  as x' = x2. Next I can find the removed x1 using x1 = x' XOR H*(x). Finally I extend x' by x' = x2 || x' XOR H*(x). Then I can get the same hash value H*(x) = H*(x')? Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Not exactly for collision, consider as you started; $x = x_1 ||x_2$ then $H^*(x) = H( H(x_1) \oplus x_2)$. Now, consider the short message, $x' = x_2$ then $H^*(x) = H(x_2)$, **What modification on $x_2$ does make this equal?** Remember $len(x) = 2 \cdot len(x')$ and this make sure that $x \neq x'$. Yes, you can find second pre-images, too ( and that will fail if the $x$ is one block)

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry :( I'm getting hung up. I have no clue about how to modify x2, the only case I can think of is when (1) = 0000, then ((1)⊕2) = (2). Could you explain how you modify x2 to me? I really appreciate your help. Perhaps you can post it as an answer I would be very happy to accept it.

Comment: Is this a sort of HW?

Comment: @kelalaka Nah, I'm new to crypto and just interested in this question in the book titled The Joy of Cryptography

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **The collision attack**

  **Collision attack means** that we need to find two distinct messages $m \neq m'$ such that $H(m) = H(m')$. We are free to choose the message as we want. This is an indication that it has a cost of $\mathcal{O}(2^{n/2})$-time with birthday attack with a probability of 50% **for secure constructions**.

  Take an arbitrary message $m$ of size at least two block $m = x_1 \mathbin\|x_2$. Then we have

  $$H^*(m) =  H\big(H(x_1) \oplus x_2\big)$$

  Now construct a new message $m'$ by modifying $m$ $$m' = H(x_1) \oplus x_2$$ this can be constructed since hashing is free. Now we have

  $$H^*(m') =  H\big(H(x_1) \oplus x_2\big)$$ Here note that $m \neq m'$ since $$\big(x_1 \mathbin\|x_2 \big)\neq \big( H(x_1) \oplus x_2\big)$$

  This procedure make the collision attack since we started the messages of our choice.
- **Equal sized messages with collision**

  The above construction used a simple modification that required one block smaller message to find a collision. **Can we make a collision of the messages that have equal sizes**? Yes, we can with these steps;

  Consider  $m = x_1 \mathbin\|x_2$ Then we have

  $$H^*(m) =  H\big(H(x_1) \oplus x_2\big)$$

  Now construct $m'= x_3 \mathbin\| a$ than

  $$H^*(m') =  H\big(H(x_3) \oplus a\big)$$

  To have a collision we need to have $$H(x_1) \oplus x_2 = H(x_3) \oplus a$$ with simple arithmetic of $\oplus$

  $$a = H(x_3) \oplus H(x_1) \oplus x_2 $$

  Now $m' = x_3 \mathbin\| \big( H(x_3) \oplus H(x_1) \oplus x_2 \big)$

  then

  \begin{align}
  H^*(m') &= H\big(H(x_3) \oplus a\big)\\
    & = H\big(H(x_3) \oplus \big( H(x_3) \oplus H(x_1) \oplus x_2 \big) \big)\\
  & = H\big( H(x_1) \oplus x_2\big) = H^*(m)\\
    \end{align}
- **Second pre-Image attack**

  In this case of **the second pre-image attack**; we are given a hash value $h$ and the input message $m$ such that $h = H^*(m)$. If the given $m$ has at least two blocks than a simple variant of the collision attack will work, only we don't choose the $m$...

Comment: It is possible with equal-sized, too.

Comment: SInce this is not HW, I've provided an answer....